# Is there any way to skip cutscenes in Puzzle Agent?

Tags: puzzle-agent

I've already played through the first bit on the iPhone (but I hated the controls), so now that I am playing it on the PC (where I like it much better), I was hoping I could skip some of the early cutscenes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I never skipped the cutscenes, but have you tried "escape"?  That usually does the trick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to skip cut scenes. I believe it's intentional by design.

Comment: Boo. :( That's a little annoying. :(